# Get already loaded images from wevbiew

Tags: android, client-server, android-webview

I want to get images from the web page and save them into the local storage. I can find all image URLs from the `HTML`, load that images from the server and save them. But I don't want to access to the server second time for the same information which is already in `webview`. So I want to know how I can load images from the `webview`?

Comment: Have you ever thougt to implement a cache system?

Comment: In this case I want to implement some kind of cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `WebView` cache in a few steps. Take a look below.

> WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_webView_Id);
>
> String cacheDir = getDir("your_WV_cache_dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
>      webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 1); // 1 Mb cache limited size >    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(cacheDir);
>      webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
>      webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK); // This        constant is important to you. This way you can load daa from cache, if it was already downloaded once.

You might take a look to th other possible values to the constant above at the [`WebView.WebSettings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) official documentation.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi yugidroid. Thank you for your quick response and sorry for being late)) Here is what I've got. I found only one `applicationCache.db` file in the `cacheDir` directory. There are 10 tables in it: `CacheGroups, sqlite_sequence, Caches, CacheWhitelistURLs, CacheAllowsAllNetworkRequests, FallbackURLs, CacheEntries, CacheResources, CacheResourceData, android_metadata`. All tables are empty except the last one, which contains only one raw: something like this 'en-EN'. And all of this I did after opening some pages in the `WebView`. So it's strange that I couldn't find any info in the cache dir.

Comment: Your are very welcome.
Have you already tried to see if the same content (supposedly in cache) is available to your app but without any kind of Internet connection?

Comment: Yes it seems all information that I need (`HTML`, images, `JS` files, `CSS` files) is cached. I wanted to make this kind of cache manually... In general this solves my problem, so I accept this answer. But now I have one more problem with cache invalidation: I want to invalidate cache only for the specific URL, not the whole cache.